# Unexpected Element Exception when Unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I need help to resolve this issue as I have tried all the proposed solutions I could find online but nothing changes the outcome.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assess xmlns="urn:test.com/2006">
    <channel>TEST</channel>
    <basicTransactionRiskData>
        <transaction>TEST</transaction>
        <classType>TestType</classType>
    </basicTransactionRiskData>
</assess>
```

Assess.Class file

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AssessBean", propOrder = {
    "channel",
    "transactionRiskData",
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "assess")
public class Assess {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String channel;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "transactionRiskData", namespace = "urn:test.com/2006", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected JAXBElement<? extends TransactionRiskDataType> transactionRiskData;
```

here is part of the exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"urn:test.com/2006", local:"assess"). Expected elements are <{urn:test.com/2006}OOBSMSChallenge>,<{
```

Marshalling works, but marshalling does not and spits out the above exception.

Let me know what else is needed to help resolve this issue!

THANKS!

Comment: How do you get unmarshller. From the error it seems you are getting it form a wrong JAXBContext.